# How to implement Merge function in keras using funtional API

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

```
print("Building model...")
ques1_enc = Sequential()
ques1_enc.add(Embedding(output_dim=64, input_dim=vocab_size, weights=[embedding_weights], mask_zero=True))
ques1_enc.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(64, seq_maxlen), return_sequences=False))
ques1_enc.add(Dropout(0.3))

ques2_enc = Sequential()
ques2_enc.add(Embedding(output_dim=64, input_dim=vocab_size, weights=[embedding_weights], mask_zero=True))
ques2_enc.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(64, seq_maxlen), return_sequences=False))
ques2_enc.add(Dropout(0.3))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([ques1_enc, ques2_enc], mode="sum"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
print("Building model costs:", time.time() - start)

print("Training...")
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=os.path.join("C:/Users/", "quora_dul_best_lstm.hdf5"), verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit([x_ques1train, x_ques2train], ytrain, batch_size=32, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1, verbose=2, callbacks=[checkpoint])
print("Training neural network costs:", time.time() - start)
```

I want to convert the above code into functional API in keras as in sequential API Merge() function is not supported. I have been trying it for long time but getting few errors. About the details of the attrributes:
ques_pairs contains the preprocessed data,
word2index contains the word count,
seq_maxlen contains the maximum length of question one or two.
iam trying to implement this model on Quora Question Pair Dataset https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs

Comment: Please add a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Only post the relevant parts of the code and try to strip your model down to the minimum

Comment: @markuscosinus hope its understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a small example, that you can apply to your own model:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Add

input1 = Input(shape=(16,))
output1 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(input1)
output1 = Dense(4, activation='relu')(output1) # Add as many layers as you like like this

input2 = Input(shape=(16,))
output2 = Dense(8, activation='relu')(input2)
output2 = Dense(4, activation='relu')(output2) # Add as many layers as you like like this

output_full = Add()([output1, output2])
output_full = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(output_full) # Add as many layers as you like like this

model_full = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output_full)
```

You need to define an `Input` for each of your model parts first, then add layers (as shown in the code) to both models. Then you can add them using the `Add` layer. Finally you call `Model` with a list of the input layers and the output layer.

`model_full` can then be compiled and trained like any other model.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like the following ?

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Sequential, Model

vocab_size = 1000
seq_maxlen = 32

embedding_weights = np.zeros((vocab_size, 64))

print("Building model...")
ques1_enc = Sequential()
ques1_enc.add(Embedding(output_dim=64, input_dim=vocab_size, weights=[embedding_weights], mask_zero=True))
ques1_enc.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(64, seq_maxlen), return_sequences=False))
ques1_enc.add(Dropout(0.3))

ques2_enc = Sequential()
ques2_enc.add(Embedding(output_dim=64, input_dim=vocab_size, weights=[embedding_weights], mask_zero=True))
ques2_enc.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(64, seq_maxlen), return_sequences=False))
ques2_enc.add(Dropout(0.3))

merge = Concatenate(axis=1)([ques1_enc.output, ques2_enc.output])
output = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(merge)
model = Model([ques1_enc.input, ques2_enc.input], output)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
```